# How to add document ID to the firestore document in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add the document ID of a new document on firestore into the object itself using python, however it shortens the string when adding and doesn't actually add the same ID.

I have printed the ID and it says it should be the same. Though in firestore its different.

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'prime_location').document()
        print('ID: ', doc_ref.id)
        docId = doc_ref.id

         # set object and push to firebase
        doc_ref.set({
                u'property_id': docId,
                u'property_address': address,
                u'number_of_beds': number_beds,
                u'number_of_baths': number_baths,
                u'property_rent': property_price,
                u'post_code': postcode,
                u'property_photo': property_image,
            })
```

An examples of this is that the id of the document is: 'aMqwOsjDbOuQmi8PZmot' but the 'property_id' value comes out as: 'YU1xd09zak...' Anybody know why this sort of behaviour is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because you are generating a random id twice.

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'prime_location').document()
        print('ID: ', doc_ref.id) //generates one id
        docId = doc_ref.id //generates the second id
```

To solve this, you sould generate a single id by calling `doc_ref.id` only once, like in the following lines of code:

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'prime_location').document()
        docId = doc_ref.id //generates id
        print('ID: ', docId) //print the generatd id
```

And then further in your code simply use the `docId` variable and **not** `doc_ref.id` which will generate another id each time is called.